# Angular lazy load submodule blank path redirect to appModule

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am working on Angular 6 project. I stuck into the following problem since the last couple of days. Please guide.

My program based on lazy routing and have dynamic routing also. The following code is my app-routing.module.ts:

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
      },
     // Here is my submodule 
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule'
      },
     // This is actually i want use to home page as blank 
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
    ];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

The following is my inner/submodule:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
    {
    path: '',
     component: UsersComponent,
    children: [
        // How can redirect to the main route
    { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: ':slug', loadChildren: './inner1/inner1.module#Inner1Module' },
    { path: ':slug/:slug2', loadChildren: './inner2/inner2.module#Inner2Module' }
    ]
    }];
    @NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
    })
```

I have two different templates for the main router outlet and inner router outlet. That why I want to redirect path as blank from inner/sub module to main module. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `userModule` route rules should look like this. Check how to have lazy-loaded modules structured in below [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10981#issuecomment-301787482)

```
export const RouteConfig: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: UsersComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
               { path: '', component: UserPage , children: [
               { path: ':slug', component: 'Inner1Component' },
               { path: ':slug/:slug2', component: 'Inner2Component' }]
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: Thanks Keshan, now I reached the actual problem.

Comment: @CodeLover Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to give a path name to your sub module and use that path  to route to your sub module and give empty path to the home module so that it is the module loaded when path is empty.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'login',
        loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
      },
     // Here is my submodule 
      {
        path: 'user-module',
        loadChildren: './users/users.module#UsersModule'
      },
     // This is actually i want use to home page as blank 
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found' }
    ];
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I try but getting an error at the inner module. Because I want to display dynamic routing in the inner module. :slug is my dynamic parameter in the inner routing. { path: ':slug', loadChildren: './inner1/inner1.module#Inner1Module' },